# PushSharp Multiline Messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I'm using PushSharp to send Android push notifications and would like to send a multiline message? Similar to how gmail notifications will sometimes show you multiple lines of an email.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try expanded layout as described in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle).